# How do I use power automate to update/overwrite existing data on a SharePoint list by toggling a checkbox on a Nintex form?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

My form is linked to a sharepoint list. In power automate, a flow has been set up so that when the check box is toggled for the first time, it populates the associated ts fields with the user and the current date. Upon completion, the associated bln field should change from false to true. Also, the associated bln field should remain true.

I cannot figure out how to add a step so that when the check box is toggled for a second or third time, it will update/overwrite the associated for the date and name. It currently only saves the information from the first user interaction.

Comment: @Ethan No, since there is no answer to that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overwriting Fields upon toggling the associated checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891745/overwriting-fields-upon-toggling-the-associated-checkbox)